# I want to check if the result($name) already exist in the database using RETURN function

Tags: php, mysqli, return-value

I want to check if the `result($name)` already exist in the database using Return function.If the `($name)` does exist already i do not want to add it to the database once more.

Right now this query does not return anything but keeps adding the same `($name)` to the database which i do not want.

How can I do it?

```
function category_exists($name){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string(connect(),$name);

    $query = mysqli_query(connect(),"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `categories` WHERE `name`='{$name}'");

    return mysqli_num_rows($query);             
    }
```

Comment: Does that query return results? What do you do with the return currently? Add some information to your question about the current issue.

Comment: Use prepared statements when you have SQL queries with variables. Don't use mysqli_real_escape_string() by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The query `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM categories WHERE name='{$name}'"` returns always a result set with one row. This row has only one column and it has the value "0" if there is not such a category or it returns the number of rows which met the condition. But either way, the result has always one row. This means that `mysqli_num_rows()` will return `1` in any case.

You must read the result of the query you send with the usual `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` functions.